# Updating to particular variable of the existing section of config file in python

Tags: python, config

I want to update a particular variable of an existing section of the config file in :Python. The config file looks like this:

```
[my_section]
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
var3 = 3
```

I am able to read the variables of the existing section (`my_section`). I want to update either of the variables `var1`, `var2`, `var3`. The code for reading and writing is given below, but the existing code overwrites the entire config file.

```
import configparser

def read_configs():
  configs = configparser.ConfigParser()
  configs.read("configs.ini")
  x=configs.get("osdp_configs","var1")
  y=configs.get("osdp_configs","var2")
  z=configs.get("osdp_configs","var3")
  print(x)
  print(type(x))
  print(y)
  print(type(y))
  print(z)
  print(type(z))
  print(configs.sections())

def write_configs():
  configs = configparser.ConfigParser()
  configs.add_section("osdp_configs")
  configs.set("osdp_configs","var1","123")
  configs.set("osdp_configs","var2","456")
  with open("configs.ini","w") as h:
      configs.write(h)

read_configs()
write_configs()
read_configs()
```

The write function `write_configs` overwrites in entire config file

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You should probably call `configs.read("configs.ini")` before you add sections and overwrite the file

Answer (score 1):

Open your configs.ini file in mode "append"

```
with open("configs.ini","a") as h:
  configs.write(h)
```

"write" mode replace all your content

Comment: The append mode "a" again forms a seperate "my section".It dosen't update the variables of the existing section